# Specifying which compiler to use

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the catkin installation it appears that cmake is using the PGI compiler available on the system I am using.  I did not explicitly tell it to use that, so I assume that it just decided that was the best one to use.  However, while building the rospack package I get an error saying that it does not recognize the -Wall switch.  I would like to force the build process to use the GNU compilers instead of the PGI one.  Where can I change this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53557/specifying-which-compiler-to-use/) by [BigBlueDart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3937/bigbluedart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/path/to/c++ --force-cmake
```

the force-cmake flag is neccessary, I just tried it out ;)

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BigBlueDart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3937/bigbluedart/) on 2013-01-29**:
It appears that I only get this issue when running catkin_make_isolated.  Running catkin_make does not appear to have the same problem recognizing flags.